# StartLockTask fails with Hardware Buttons

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, kiosk-mode

I have gone through the provisioning and ownership requirements to use `SetLockTaskPackages()` and `StartLockTask()`. In the emulators the `StartLockTask()` works as expected. The on-screen buttons are removed and message *"Unpinning isn't allowed by your organization."* is displayed on the screen.

This method seems to work good on supported devices for locking the user into a kiosk like environment. Although some devices, such as the *Samsung Galaxy TabA 7*, have hardware buttons. Even though the user is told *"Unpinning isn't allowed by your organization."* they can still use the hardware button combination to exit the application.

My solution for this was to detect the `OnLockTaskModeExiting` then notify my `MainActivity` to re-apply my policies and `StartLockTask()`

So I made `EventPasser` class. It's job is to raise an event from `DeviceAdminReceiver` to my `MainActivity`.

```
    public class EventPasser
    {
        public static event EventHandler ScreenUnlocked;

        public static void RaiseUnlockEvent()
        {
            EventHandler handler = ScreenUnlocked;
            if (null != handler) handler(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

In my `DeviceAdminReceiver` I listen for `OnLockTaskModeExiting` and raise an event that is attached in my `MainActivity.`

```
    public class DeviceAdmin : DeviceAdminReceiver
    {
        public override void OnLockTaskModeExiting(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            base.OnLockTaskModeExiting(context, intent);

            // Raise our Unlock Event
            EventPasser.RaiseUnlockEvent();

        }
     }
```

In my `MainActivity` on the `OnCreate` I hook up to the static event.

```
    EventPasser.ScreenUnlocked += EventPasser_ScreenUnlocked;
```

The event just re-applies my locking policies and `StartLockTask()`.

```
    private void EventPasser_ScreenUnlocked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterAndLock();
    }
```

This works very well asides from the small annoyance that you see the message *"Application locked on screen".*

I am a c# programmer, not quite yet an Android developer. I am very new to Android and I have solved this the way that I know how. I feel like I should be able to avoid this *event passing solution* I just don't know how.

Is there a more direct way to re-apply my `StartLockTask()` packages on `OnLockTaskModeExiting`? 
Or even better; is there a way to enforce the `StartLockTask()` to respect hardware buttons?

Comment: On Samsung devices that support "Knox" (also called "My Knox"), you can control the physical device buttons via Knox Setting in global settings of the device. There are MDMs that somehow can remotely control those settings on Samsung devices so there is an device admin level API for them but I have personally never seen it as a publicly available API (maybe you have to a Samsung partner/licensor). If we are not using Samsung Knox tablets for kiosk devices, then we avoid physical hardware button-based devices (also some clients build locked covers that "hide" phy. buttons for some models).

Comment: This is a really helpful comment. Thank you

Comment: How did you get device ownership?

Comment: @JP4 Ownership requires ADB commands executed with the android device physically connected and factory reset. Look into `adb shell dpm set-device-owner`